# For Loop in C; but there isn't any curly braces

Tags: c

I've searched for this on Google, but obviously having the word For and C, so many irrelevant searches appear.

I've just started reading The C Programming Language - Second Edition, but there is one section that is confusing me. The For Loop. In most other major languages (barring Python) the For Loop will be nested with curly braces after the (init; condition; increment), however in this example there isn't:

```
for (fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
```

Is this because of the book being old and therefore the syntax may be different to what it is now? If not can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: If there is no curly braces then it will include just next line until it finds `;`(semicolon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have been reading pretty quickly.

I'm rather sure the book explains that a statement can be either simple, in which case it's just a single statement terminated by `;`, or compound in which case it's a list of statements enclosed by `{` and `}`.

The body of the `for` loop is a statement, and can thus be either simple or compound.

Of course the wording above is recursive, which is intentionally. This is perfectly valid:

```
for(fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr += 20)
{
  printf("%d", fahr);
  {
    printf(" %6.1f", (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32));
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

It's of course an utterly annoying and pointless way to write this very simple loop, but it illustrates that wherever there can be a statement, there can be a compound statement. This is sometimes handy if you want a "more local" variable, especially in pre-C99 versions of the language.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I'm pretty sure it's not in there - unless it is slightly further in than where I am. But either way thank you for answering my question. I was always taught to use braces whether it is one statement or multiple, so I guess it's a case of my ignorance to believing what I was taught. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

by default next statement to  `for(...)` loop other then comment will be considered as body of the loop. however it is good to put it. curly braces is must if you want it should be treated as body of any construct.

```
for(...)
  {
    // body of the loop
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this, makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are not need when one statement needs to be executed by a `for` loop. However,if multiple statements needs to be looped by the `for` , you need the curly braces.

In your case,the printf is considered as the body of the loop and it will be executed until the condition in the `for` becomes false. But it is a good practice to include the braces as it increases the legibility of the code as well as prevent mistakes which might happen in the future when editing the program.

This is the same for `while`,`if` etc

Comment: Thanks, was always taught to use curly braces, so I guess it was my ignorance taking precedence and should've kept an open mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic C syntax, that has been valid since the dawn of time (well, since the early 70s, but [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) considers that the dawn of time). The body of a `for` loop is always a statement. A statement can either be simple, like the one you show, or a *block* of statements in curly braces. So you only need the braces if the body contains multiple statements. I'm pretty sure K&R explain this somewhere.

This is true in C, C++, D, Java and Objective-C. Perl and Go are the exceptions.

I would add, though, that putting in the curly braces even though they're not necessary doesn't hurt, and I've adopted these "useless" braces as part of my coding style, to prevent mistakes like

```
if (condition)
    do_one_thing();
    and_another_thing();
```

which can creep into code when editing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should've kept an open mind when reading the book instead of resting on my laurels of what I have been taught to code, using braces with everything - one line or not! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In C if the construct, control or selection body contains only a single statment, then it is not necessary to include it in braces

That is

```
for (fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
```

is treated same as

```
for (fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
{
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
}
```